# Can I do multiple countdown in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Need help
Can i do this in void Update() ?

```cs
public float waitTime = 3f;
float timer;

void Update () {
  // I will do anything here then,
  timer += Time.deltaTime; // start counting

 // If timer become 3 seconds
  if (timer > waitTime) {
      timer = 0f; // to reset timer back to 0 again
  }

 // I will do the next command here then,

  timer += Time.deltaTime; // start counting again

 // If timer become 3 seconds
  if (timer > waitTime) {
      timer = 0f; // to reset timer back to 0 again
  }

  // I will do the next command here then so on,
}
```

Or maybe there is another way? Need help again

Comment: What did you mean? You want to call  a different command every 3 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that wouldn't work:

In `Update`, when you reach the first `timer = 0f`, for the rest of the function, you timer is 0 so the second event will never trigger. On the next frame, you will start over at the top and after 3 seconds, reach the first event again.

There are several solutions. To get a simple solution using your code, you can save the number of commands you already executed:

```cs
public float waitTime = 3f; 
private float timer;
private int currentCommand = 0;

void Update () 
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime; 

    if (timer > waitTime) 
    {
        timer -= waitTime; // this is more exact than setting it to 0: timer might be a bit greater than waitTime

        // The first time the timer reaches 3s, it will call ExecuteCommand with argument 0
        // The second time, with argument 1, and so on
        ExecuteCommand(currentCommand);
        currentCommand++;
    }
}

private void ExecuteCommand(int command)
{
    switch(command)
    {
        case 0: //HERE Code for command 0
            return;
        case 1: //HERE Code for command 0
            return;
        // as many as you want
    }
}
```

---

Another nice way would be to take advantages of [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Coroutines are a bit tricky if you are a begginer. These are functions that can be stopped in the middle and resumed later. With a coroutine you could do something like

```cs
void Start () 
{
    StartCoroutine("CommandRoutine");
}

private void IEnumerator CommandRoutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

    // HER CODE FOR COMMAND 1

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

    // HER CODE FOR COMMAND 2

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

    // And so on
}
```

If you don't know coroutines, my first example will be simpler for you to understand, but it can be a nice occasion to try coroutine if you are interested.

Comment: There's a very slight possibility of the second command being executed in the original script, as there are TWO `+= Time.deltaTime` lines, but in general, yes.

Comment: Nice it helps me now. I hope I can learn more in this community with you guys :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Regarding the button, yes it can be done, but that is a different question. You should try to make it work by yourself, then if you are stuck somewhere, open a new question with your code, what you want it to do and why it doesn't work. Good luck